# Need a table that can sort, lock

Tags: looking-for-a-script, javascript, html5, jquery, table

I need table that will be able to:

1. sort
2. lock columns
3. lock the header row
4. resize columns
5. scroll
6. if possible can add/remove columns.

Was hoping to able to do this with jquery / html5 and have all data client side - so no server requests.

I have tried:

1. http://www.datatables.net/ has no locking, resizing of columns
2. http://tablesorter.com/docs/ similarly has no locking, resizing of columns.

Comment: what do you mean by locking? What can you do to the examples of 1 and 2 that you don't want to be able to do?

Comment: Also, how is locking the header row different from the table being scrollable? I'm interpreting those as the same thing.

Comment: Say have I have 20 columns.  That means I'll have a horizontal scrollbar.  I'd like to be able to lock the first three columns.  So that they don't scroll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataTable [*can* lock columns](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/two_columns.html), and there's a [plugin](http://datatables.net/extras/) that adds the ability to resize them. (There's no good anchor; just do an in-page search for "resize.")

[Flexigrid](http://flexigrid.info/) will do everything on your list, except for the column locking.